# modulerr in filter test jasmine/angular injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I am trying to run an Angular test on my filter 'manufacturerFilter'.

```
describe('productApp', function() {
    var manufacturerFilter;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('productApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$filter_) {
        manufacturerFilter = _$filter_('manufacturerFilter');
    }));

    it('has a manufacturerFilter filter', function() {
        expect(manufacturerFilter.not.toBeNull());
    });

});
```

And getting the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http:// errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=ui.bootstrap&p1=Error%3A%20%5Bng%3Aareq%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0-rc.0%2Fng%2Fareq%3Fp0%3Dfn%26p1%3Dnot%2520a%2520function%252C%2520got%2520string%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A421%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Jb%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A466)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20kb%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A47)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Rb%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A93)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.e%20%5Bas%20invoke%5D%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A142)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A34%3A192%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A296)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20f%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A33%3A419)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.Hb%20%5Bas%20injector%5D%20(https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A99)
```

App:

```
var myApp = angular.module('productApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Filter:

```
myApp.filter('manufacturerFilter', function() {
return function(input, $scope) {

 // filter code

  }
});
```

This worked previously, but after adding some code, mainly the dependecy on ui-bootstrap, the tests are not failing. The execution doesn't even seem to reach the assertion, but fails when injecting the filter?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it like that:

```
describe('productApp', function() {
    var manufacturerFilter;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('productApp');
        inject(function(_$filter_) {
            manufacturerFilter = _$filter_('manufacturerFilter');
        });
    });

    it('has a manufacturerFilter filter', function() {
        expect(manufacturerFilter.not.toBeNull());
    });

});
```